# GPO Setting to allow workstations to use VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, group-policy, watchguard

Is there a GPO setting that allows non-admins access to change their network settings. Which is what the SSLVPN does? If so, what is it?

Background : 
I've got a few laptops that are used by Domains admins, that can access the Watchguard SSLVPN. But we now have end users that need remote access, and it seems Windows wont let the VPN software to update their Network Settings.

I'm trying to determine if it's a GPO setting preventing the user from accessing the info.
When we remove the laptop from the domain, the VPN works for the user.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to answer the question.

Comment: I gave you background info, but really I want to know if there is a GPO setting that allows non-admins access to change their network settings. Which is what the SSLVPN does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Network settings" is pretty broad, and like I said in my comment, you haven't really given us enough information to give a good answer, but below is a screenshot of the default configuration options available to you via the Group Policy Management Editor, after you install the Administrative Templates for Group Policy.

<kbd>User Configuration</kbd> -> <kbd>Policies</kbd> -> <kbd>Administrative Templates</kbd> -> <kbd>Network</kbd> -> <kbd>Network Connections</kbd>

[image]

The `prohibit changing properties of a private remote access connection` configuration seems promising...